# How to catch the re-open app even in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

Do you know how to catch the event then user click on the APP icon, and APP still in the Memory, so I can run the simple check: 'Is it still the same day'

I checked for AppLifecyccleState, but seems is outdated.
Should I run the background task that will check the day change in the background??

App is build with flutter for IOS and Android

Best,
Alex

Comment: Can you share some more details about what you want to?

Comment: @JigarFumakiya Let's say you open app number 1 (my), then switch to another one, and then go back to app number 1. I want to catch the event then the user re-open the app again after it been paused

Comment: @Alex 
ok got it then WidgetBinding observer is a way to do it 
I see you are using it did you face any problem with that?

Comment: @JigarFumakiya ok, thanks! will play with it right now, seems like it works.
Will post the code then it will be properly tested, thanks!

Comment: I found the solution, thank you @JigarFumakiya for navigating me. Here it is: https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-lifecycle-manager-to-manage-your-services-b9c928d3aed7

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem you can find here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-lifecycle-manager-to-manage-your-services-b9c928d3aed7